# Actionscript data entry question

Tags: actionscript, precision, textinput

```
 <s:TextInput id="bill" x="150" y="17" width="223" 
 borderColor="#FFFBFB" borderVisible="false"  
 color="#EF4315" contentBackgroundColor="#100101"
 enabled="false" fontWeight="bold" restrict="0-9" 
 text="0.00" textAlign="right"/>
```

"0-9" restricts my textInput field to numeric values 
and a decimal point. Is there a way I can extend this so only
two places follow the decimal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not. But you can listent to CHANGE Event and programmatically force this on the TextInput.